# how to run netbeans pltform App without installing the netbeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans-7

I created an application with the NetBeans platform, and I want to run my App on another computer where the netbeans IDE was not installed.

Please suggest to me, how can I run my application without the NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on your project's main module
2. Choose "Package As --> Intallers" from the context menu
3. Copy the installer from the dist directory of your main module to the target computer
4. Run the installer on the target computer

Alternatively you can also create a ZIP distribution instead of an installer in 2)

Comment: sir/mem this done very well for windows , but it is not work exactly for MAC and Linux, so please suggest to me for run this App on MAC and Linux without installing netbeans IDE on MAC and Linux.

Comment: Either use the ZIP Distribution or create the installers for MAC and Linux (it's in the same menu)

Comment: sir/mem i done it but it give that type of error.in which thw F; if my drive of pc , java is folder name , GMD App is my application name. so what i have to do for solution of this error. Warning: Could not find file F:\java\GMD App\dist\gmd_app.app\Contents\Resources\gmd_app\gmd_app\etc\gmd_app.icns to copy.

Comment: sir/mem i done it, i go to my main project and right click, and then projrct>Properties>installers and then i tik the installer for MAC ,Linux and Windows, and Solaries. after thet it work well.